# i got "login failure all modules ignored" exception when i try to use my custom login module on jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jaas

**i got "login failure all modules ignored" exception when i try to use my custom login module on jboss 7.1 . i am trying to use my module as jboss module and as lib class but i got this exception and this is the stack:**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8088-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:921) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:361) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:381) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved now, I just need to throw LoginException in wrong cases

Comment: Can you provide code example? I also have the problem and throwing LoginException does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR if you see `all modules ignored`, it means every LoginModule returned `false`. Every LoginModule either chose to be ignored or decided that the login failed.

This message is being generated by a Java security layer, Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS). There is useful info in the [Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-authentication-and-authorization-service-jaas-loginmodule-developers-guide1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-EE1C4BBE-289F-4419-A233-43F2D897765B) and [Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html).

There should be a configuration file, usually named `auth.conf`, which contains a list of classes to load. Each listed class must implement `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`. `login()` is called, sequentially, in every module listed in `auth.conf`, as explained in [Appendix B](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html#AppendixB) of the Reference Guide. Then `commit()` is called on every module.

A LoginModule can decide that it doesn't know how to handle a certain login. In that case it should return `false` from `login()`, which indicates that it should be ignored. [Relevant section in the Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-authentication-and-authorization-service-jaas-loginmodule-developers-guide1.htm#GUID-E9C5810B-ADB6-4454-869D-B269ECA8145F__LOGINMODULE.LOGINMETHOD-21144491):

> If this LoginModule should be ignored, login should return false.
>
> Throw a LoginException such as FailedLoginException if authentication fails.

Much documentation **incorrectly** states that returning `false` indicates failure, so many LoginModules are implemented that way.

If you see `LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored`, it means either that you have no LoginModules configured in `auth.conf`, or that the `login()` method of every configured LoginModule returned `false`. Returning `false` could either mean that they don't know how to handle the login or that the login failed.

You can add `debug=true` to the end of the line in `auth.conf` to ask the LoginModule to provide additional logging, although there is no guarantee that they will.

```
project {
  com.example.auth.ConsoleLoginModule required debug=true;
}
```